# How to log messages to a log file in a specific path from a bash script

Tags: bash, logging, syslog

How do you log messages to a log file in a specific path from a bash script?

A naive implementation would be commands like:

```
echo My message >>/my/custom/path/to/my_script.log
```

But this probably has many disadvantages (no log rotation for example).
I could use the 'logger' command, but it does not support logs in custom paths as far as I know and is not easy to configure if you have lots of bash scripts that could use a custom log file.

In a scripting language like Ruby all this is quite easy: https://github.com/rudionrails/yell/wiki/101-the-datefile-adapter
I could also make my own logger command based on this ruby library and call it from my bash scripts, but I guess there is already a well known solution that provides similar behavior for shell scripts?

Comment: `logger` just sends the data to syslog. Your syslog configuration can handle splitting it into the log file of your choosing. Syslog does not rotate logs, that is usually done by logrotate, which can be configured for use on any file.

Comment: I was wondering if a solution exists where you run something like 'simply_log -f ~/log/foo.log My message' which logs the message to that file and rotates that log file when necessary. (I.e. similar behavior to logging commands in modern scripting languages).

Comment: IMO using a system wide logrotate program is preferred unless you are restricted to a user account on the server. Especially when one of the most popular logging libraries has [catastrophic bugs](http://juliusdavies.ca/logging.html#rotate)

Comment: So, if you have tens of personal custom scripts in your ~/bin/ directory which could really use some logging, then it would be preferred to log it to the syslog?

Comment: It really depends on what they are doing. You could just append the date to the log file name and not worry about rotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply append text to a log file from a bash script in that way:

```
echo "My message" >> /my/custom/path/to/my_script.log
```

Rotation is handled by logrotate, you just need to add the settings to the .conf in /etc/logrotate.conf. The config is pretty self explanatory and the man page is also quite helpful, but in short if you want to rotate weekly and keep 4 weeks worth of logs in compressed format and create a new empty log as it rotates out the last, you would simply put in the .conf:

```
/my/custom/path/to/my_script.log {
    rotate 4
    weekly
    create
    compress
    endscript
}
```

There are many other options you can check out at the man page (man logrotate) such as emailing the log files, executing commands on rotation, rotate when the files reach a certain size, etc.